When authors write "model of the data" is this a shorthand for "model of the data generating process"
Some authors, such as Barber in Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning and Rasmussen & Williams in Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning, write phrases such as "model of the data" and "modelling the data". Is this a shorthand for "model of the data generating process" and "modelling the data generating process"?

Edit:
This question is different from the question Why do we use term “population” instead of “Data-generating process”?, as I'm not really interested in the philosophical issues related to how the data is generated. Therefore its accepted answer doesn't really help me here.
What I want to see clarified is if the phrase "model of the data" really makes sense by itself, or if it is simply an instance of abuse of terminology and should more correctly be written as "model of the system that we measured/observed" instead.

I think not in general.  Take for example your first link saying "The word ‘causal’ is contentious particularly in cases where the model of the data contains no explicit temporal information, so that formally only correlations or dependencies can be inferred." Later it uses a longer form in "We assume however, that we
make no detailed model of the data generating mechanism, asking rather generic questions such as whether the results support some basic hypothesis such as whether two classifiers are performing differently."

@Henry, I am not sure I follow. Did you set up the stage for a counterexample but then provide an example?

In my opinion, data and models live in different worlds. Data are part of the "real world" while models are in the "world of ideas." Therefore, it is better to write "a model FOR the data."

@Ben, while that linked answer is interesting from a philosophical point of view, (I think that) my issue is more on the semantic level. When we talk about mathematical models we mean "an abstract description of a system using mathematical concepts and language".  We then use observations/measurements (the data) of the system that we intended to describe in order to fit the model to it. So the phrases "model of the data" and "modelling the data" become confusing in this context, unless it is always the case that it is a shorthand to "model of the system that we measured".

You say you're not interested in the philosophical issues, but what we are doing and talking about here is necessarily partly a philosophical question.

@NickCox, don't see how, but if can explain it to me I would be thankful. I'm not a native speaker so in my head I currently see it as a language issue. Either way, I see modeling the DGP or a measured characteristic of a Population as modeling a system, not as modeling the data.

Statistical people like anybody else tend to use expressions they think will be understood by their readership. Do you fit the data to the model or the model to the data? I tend to say the second, but I've seen both. Is the population a set of people (places, things) being sampled or the set of values being sampled? It could be either. If I am looking at people's heights and weights, I don't feel a need to talk about a system behind the data or a data generating process, but there are contexts where that is a good idea.

So for you, modeling the data itself might be valid in some contexts?

I wouldn't say valid or invalid. It's not an expression I much like or recommend. I might have used it informally. I think much depends on whether your data are in time, space, space-time, or something else. But there are always underlying processes, yet analyses differ greatly in how far those processes are from the data being analysed. With people's heights and weights, there is always a context in terms of age, heredity, environment, people's histories of diet and disease, and so forth, but often there are data on much more than say age.  Processes are usually inferred, not observed.

Ok, I think I would more or less accept that answer... If you want reopen the question and submit it, I would appreciate it.

I can't re-open the question unilaterally. At most I could vote to re-open the question, but to be frank I doubt it's worth it. Good if you found my comments helpful.
